# How to accept input from one of two textboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm working on a page that accepts input from only one of two textboxes when a checkbox is checked. I tried making a TextChanged event for the first text box that would disable the second textbox but it doesn't work. Here's my code for the textboxes, thanks in advance!

```
function initSurchargeFields() {
  var $chk = $("#chkSurcharge");
  $chk.click(chkSurcharge_onclick);

  var $txt = $("#txtSurcharge");
  var $txta = $("#txtSurcharge1");

  if (!$chk[0].checked) {
    $txt[0].disabled = "disabled";
    $txta[0].disabled = "disabled";
  }
} 

function chkSurcharge_onclick(event) {
  var $txt = $get("txtSurcharge");
  var $txta = $get("txtSurcharge1");

  $txt.disabled = this.checked ? "" : "disabled";
  $txta.disabled = this.checked ? "" : "disabled";

  if (this.checked) {
    txt.focus();
  }
```

```csharp
protected void txtSurcharge_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtSurcharge1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: `$get("txtSurcharge");`  What is this?  Also when working the the object property 'checked' it is expected to have a value of true or false.  You are changing the property on the object, not a markup attribute.  Furthermore if $txt is a jQuery object `$txt.disabled` will not work as disabled is not exposed on the jQuery object.  You'll have to do [0].disabled like in the other place or use `prop('disabled', boolean)`

Comment: looks like javascript to me, does the txtSucharge_TextChanged method even run?

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is make it so that when I add text to txtSurcharge, txtSurchage1 gets disabled and vice versa. So far this is just disabling and enabling them when the checkbox is checked. I just need the program to disable the opposite textbox when one of them has text inputted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery so:

To check if a check box is checked you need to:

```
$("#chkSurcharge").is(":checked")
```

To set a property value you need to:

```
$("#txtSurcharge").prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to toggle the "disabled" attribute using jquery [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). This is is an alternative to [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for attributes such as "disabled" that can be toggled with a boolean.

Also, you need to set an onclick event handler properly. I did this with jquery [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
function initSurchargeFields() {
    var $chk = $("#chkSurcharge");
    $chk.on('click', chkSurcharge_onclick);

    var $txt = $("#txtSurcharge");
    var $txta = $("#txtSurcharge1");

    if (!$chk.is(':checked')) {
        $txt.prop('disabled', true);
        $txta.prop('disabled', true);
    }
} 
function chkSurcharge_onclick(event) {

    var $txt = $("#txtSurcharge");
    var $txta = $("#txtSurcharge1");

    $txt.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    $txta.prop('disabled', !this.checked);

    if (this.checked) {
        $txt.focus();
    }
}
```

Tip: Make sure you're using Chrome or IE developer tools to set breakpoints and debug your javascript as you code. It's just like debugging c# in visual studio.